# Changing images to a site depending on culture

Tags: asp.net

i'm trying to change the ImageButton on my site using resx files. i tried assigning my ImageButton with meta:ResourceKey="imgBtnSubmit". then in my resx file, i added imgBtnSubmit.ImageUrl and assigned it the url to my new ImageButton. this didn't work for me. could someone tell me if i'm doing something wrong or if there is some other way i could do this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers but i got it working without having to create a custom ExpressionBuilder. there's a built-in 'Resources' ExpressionBuilder. This is what i did:

```
<asp:imagebutton runat="server" id="img1" ImageUrl="<%$Resources:ImageName%>"/>
```

default.aspx.resx:

```
ImageName ----- English_Image_Button.jpg
```

default.aspx.es.resx:

```
ImageName ----- Spanish_Image_Button.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it writing a custom ExpressionBuilder.

That way you can influence the ImageUrl location based on your cultureinfo.

It would look like:

```
<asp:imagebutton runat="server" id="img1" ImageUrl="<%$ ImageResources: newItem.png %>" />
```

ImageResources is the name of the custom expressionbuilder. I my case i just needed to know the name of the image. I put my images in /app_themes/[theme name]/images/[culturecode] so my expressionbuilder creates that url based on the provided file name, current theme and culturecode.

Comment: I must comment that the previous answer is a good one too. It's how i am doing it now :)
Nevertheless, my solution works perfectly if you have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something else you may like to consider is having your buttons with a background image (or faking a button with some other element which has a background image), and overlaying the text. You will then be able to change the text based on culture without having to change the background image.

Comment: This will work as long as your background image doesn't change along the X-axis.  Things like rounded corners will get stretched or compressed based on the length of the text, which won't look pleasant.

Comment: well, you can split the image up into the sides/corners and with a bit of css it can look fine